# Should I pay every year for keep devexpress app running

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, publish

Should I pay every year for keep asp.net web forms with **devexpress UI** project running? I used trial version to create it, but what about after publish?

Comment: Not every year. If you do not want support and product updates then you can keep you older version dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sides to this question.

Firstly when you buy a DevExpress product license there are two "components" to the license. The first part is a perpetual license to use the product. The second is the update/upgrade "maintenance" part where you get all the updates, upgrades, and bug fixes to the product. It also includes support for the product. This latter part is provided on an annual basis. The initial license purchase covers both of these, the subsequent renewals are all about ensuring you have the latest code and can be supported.

So, taking it on that level: of course it is fine to buy a license and never renew it. If you have a one-off app, all you need to do is buy the product, write the app, and never change it again.

Secondly, there is the issue where sometime down the road (say, a new browser version, changes to JavaScript, updates to ASP.NET WebForms) means that your app has a bug. Perhaps at that time, you don't care and just retire the app. Perhaps it has to continue in use, so you have to purchase the license again. Fine and dandy, except you may find other issues in updating that app after a few years of being static: the product has changed, the run-time has changed, the IDE has changed, etc. How long would it take you (and cost you) to fix the app? Is that future cost greater than the cost of renewing through the years? A classic Time-Value-Of-Money calculation, I think.

Answer (score 3):

There are no need to pay every year. Once you purchased DevExpress license, you can use it forever.

According to [DevExpress Licensing FAQ](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/licensingfaq.xml):

> All DevExpress products are sold based on a subscription model. This
>   means that when you purchase a Subscription, you receive 12 months of
>   free updates for that product(s) from the date of purchase - be it a
>   minor service update or a major new version. After the 12 month period
>   and at your discretion, you can pay about 45% of original price to
>   "renew" the subscription and receive another 12 months of free
>   updates. If you choose not to renew, you can continue using the last
>   version you obtained or are eligible to use. The 12 month time frame
>   is merely for new versions/updates and does not apply to rights of use
>   (as long as the EULA is not violated).